# How do I create multiple views into the same notebook in jupyterlab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

When debugging code it is natural to have one "editing" window and one "interacting" window. This isn't so easy to do with jupyterlab.

Is there a way of having two or more views into the same notebook? I found this which claimed this feature: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87ALbxm1Y3I but it didn't seem to work for notebooks.

---

From krassowski's link below, you need to right click on the tab (not the file in my video) and click the button creating a new view.

Comment: Yse. Please read/watch the documentation at https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/notebook.html (search for "Create multiple synchronized views of a single notebook").

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for notebooks [opened from Rmd](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext/issues/8) you get a file editing the raw Rmd file.

Comment: I believe that this issue was solved already very recently; not sure if it was already released or if it's only going into yet-to-be-released 4.0.